# Is process address space part of Process Control Block(PCB)?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I recently read about the process address space and PCB and trying to link them together. I don't find much literature on their relation.

Is the process address space a part of the PCB data structure?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, [task_struct](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/sched.h#L632) is the closest you can get to PCB. Process address space is the memory mappings. Memory mapping is not stored in `task_struct`. Thus, the answer is a big fat NO.